# regex: match on negating a set of abitrary whitespaces before and after a 'comment' character

Tags: regex, comments

I am looking for a regex to (non)match a comment character wrapped by arbitrary whitespaces

For example with '#' as comment character:

lines supposed to be match:

```
 code line here
   code line here
```

lines supposed to be *not* matched:

```
 #code line here
 # code line here
   #   code line here
```

So, something like a negation of the set (zero/*whitespaces # zero/*whitespaces)

```
 ^(\s#\s)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your own regex?

Comment: the two whitespaces are not 'concenated' into one whitespace range, so the regexp does not match any uncommented line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something not optimized, but try this:

```
^[^#]*(?!\s*#).
```

This will get all symbols from the beginning of the line that are not followed by `spaces + #` combination.

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will match lines that don't have the character "#"

```
^((?!^\s+#).)*$
```

Comment: This regex doesn't capture code lines ending with comment.

Comment: @AlexL, It's not a requirement on the question, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, if lookahead is supported you could use a negative lookahead to assert that from the start of the string what is on the right is not 0+ times a whitespace char followed by a `#`.

If that is the case, then match the whole string.

```
^(?!\s*#).+$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `\s*#` Match 0+ times a whitespace char, then `#`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char except newline 1+ times
- `$` End of the string

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFtsS9/1)